# Быстрый поиск по ключу среди пары ключ-значение

Tags: c, hashmap

Имеется два массива, размером, например, десять элементов:

1. В первом храняться значения X-ов:

   const uint64_t X[10] = {2,5,7,15,95,100,1001,1002,1003,100500};
2. Во втором хранятся Y-ки:

   const double Y[10] = {1.01,2.002,4.05,16.95,100.01,125.458,998.87,2115.10,4050.002,0.0};

Очевидно, что в реальной задаче размер этих массивов далеко не 10, поэтом требуются дополнительные средства для быстрого обращения к его элементам без прямого перебора.

Начитался о бинарных деревьях, hash-таблицах и ассоциативных массивах. В принципе, всё понятно, только есть одно "НО".

Пусть дан X равный 8; Можно обратить внимание на то, что в массиве X-ов его нет.

В программе нужно из указанной таблицы получить диапазон X-ов, которому пренадлежит заданный X == 8 ; В текущем примере это X1 = 7; и X2 = 15; Естественно, затем и игреки, соответствующие этим иксам. Y1 = 4.05; и Y2 = 15.95;

Если преобразовать данные из обеих массивов в hash-таблицу, где X-ы будут ключами, а Y-ки значением, то, как я понял, мне это всё-равно не поможет. Неизвестно по какому ключу обращаться для получения значения. У меня есть только число 8, которого нет среди ключей.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне решить мою задачу?

Как-то эта проблема решена в реляционных базах данных...

Вот например, я могу сделать два запроса:

```
SELECT X,Y FROM tablename WHERE X < 8 ORDER BY X DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT X,Y FROM tablename WHERE X > 8 ORDER BY X ASC LIMIT 1;
```

И получить два результа - пары X:Y в искомом диапазоне:

```
7  | 4.05
15 | 16.95
```

Для моих задач БД - это слишком много накладных расходов. Хотелось бы решить задачу алгоритмически. Предполагаю, что до меня этот велосипед давно изобрели и реализовали в виде сишной библиотеки )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем случае проще будет реализовать поиск элемента (или диапазона, при отсутствии искомого элемента) с помощью [бинарного поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA), немного изменив алгоритм и возвращать структуру из двух индексов, если они равны, то это искомый элемент, если нет, то это необходимый Вам диапазон.

Для модификации поиска храните значения индексов предыдущего шага и если поиск закончится неудачей то значения предыдущего шага и будут необходимым диапазоном.

Comment: Алексей, спасибо за полензную информацию! Возможно ли подкрепить теорию практическими примерами или ссылками на таковые? Без примера с трудом могу себе представить алгоритм.

Comment: например вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-c