# Какой наиболее эффективный алгоритм сортировки при условии, что данные в массив поступают по одному элементу?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, qsort

Алгоритмов сортировки множество. Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, какой алгоритм будет наиболее производительным в моём случае (быстрее работать). Расходы по памяти непринципиальны. Данные в массив поступают по одному элементу. Например в массив:

```
2 4 6 7 8 10
```

в следующей итерации будет добавлено только одно число 5. После чего массив должен быть пересортирован, и принять следующий вид:

```
2 4 5 6 7 8 10
```

Буду рад любым рекомендациям, названиям алгоритма/ов или любым намёкам. Сейчас пересортировую банальным qsort после каждого добавления нового элемента в сишной программе. Но предполагаю, что можно поступать гораздо эффективнее.

Comment: При вставке нового значения в отсортированный массив бинарным поиском ищете позицию для вставки. Массиву желательно быть не массивом, а списком, поскольку операция вставки для массива не константная операция. Для небольших массивов можно забить на бинарный поиск и искать линейно.

Comment: Для чего нужен отсортированный (после каждой вставки) массив?

Comment: @MBo Для бинарного поиска

Comment: А, уже увидел в комментарии к ответу. Воспользуйтесь ответом Harry, он прав, для вас это хороший вариант.

Comment: @MBo Спасибо. Сейчас как-раз читаю об особенностях красно-чёрных деревьев.

Comment: @vp_arth Большое спасибо за совет! Массив большой. Про вставку внутрь массива после бинарного поиска - идея очень понравилась. Просто и гениально! Списки не подходят, увы. Буду исследовать вариант со вставкой или рекомендуемые тут красно-чёрные деревья.

Comment: Типичная XY-задача. Вам нужен *быстрый поиск по ключу*, а не *отсортированный массив* - так воспользуйтесь хешированием. Для быстрого поиска отсортированность необходимым условием не является... Всегда лучше указать конечную задачу, а не промежуточную. Грубо говоря, не надо спрашивать, как добраться от Москвы до Челябинска, даже если вы знаете короткую дорогу из Челябинска до Тулы... :)

Comment: Вам нужен именно *массив* или любой контейнер с возможностью быстрого поиска? Если любой контейнер, то опишите, какие операции с ним как целым и с его элементами собираетесь делать.

Comment: @avp Подробнее о цели вот тут: ["Быстрый поиск по ключу среди пары ключ-значение"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/982826/246927)

Comment: @Harry Увы, но в моём случае далеко не все алгоритмы подойдут. Мне нужно сделать не так, как обычно - найти одно ключ-значение среди многих. Мне нужно найти _все_ (а не одно) значения меньше 9 и больше 3 из примера выше. Если обратите внимание, то ни 9, ни 3 в массиве не найдёте. Поэтому задача является далеко не классической.

Comment: @Harry В отсортированном массиве я сначала бинарным поиском найду 8, как наиболее близкое к 9, потом двигаясь в обратном направлении выберу все числа до 4 включительно. В случае с деревьями, например, мне прийдётся пройтись **по всему** дереву для реализации второго шага.

Comment: @DennisV.R. Вам никто не мешает модернизировать дерево так, что в нем будет, например, дополнительный указатель на предыдущий/следующий элемент - причем цена такого указателя - O(1). Перефразируя Ленина, алгоритмы - не догма, а руководство к действию :)

Comment: @Harry Если добавить дополнительный указатель на предыдущий/следующий элемент, то лёгким движением руки дерево превращается в двусвязный список. Если сравнивать его с сортированным массивом, то кроме дополнительных накладных расходов по памяти он ещё и будет медленнее работать на поиск (как я понимаю сам алгоритм). Да, вставка будет быстрее. Но мне нужно наоборот, чтобы поиск работал быстрее. У меня на миллиард поисков не больше одной вставки.

Comment: Вы совсем не читаете, что я пишу? Еще раз: красно-черное дерево с **дополнительными** полями. А не заменить красно-черное дерево двусвязным списком. Поиск будет O(log N), переход к соседнему элементу - O(1). А, впрочем, что я тут распинаюсь и разжевываю? делайте, как хотите, ваша программа, не моя...

Comment: @Harry Большое спасибо за уточнение! Без обид! Я не сразу понял какую функцию выполняют дополнительные поля. Теперь сижу изучаю крассно-чёрные деревья.

Comment: @DennisV.R., по ссылке, которой вы мне ответили все же другая задача, с поиском по любому члену пары. Вы бы толком написали тут, в тексте вопроса, **все требования** (т.е. набор всех операций) с вашеими данными. Если же остановиться на том, что вы описываете и учесть замечание в одном из комментариев -- *`"У меня на миллиард поисков не больше одной вставки"`*, то выбор очевиден -- ***линейный массив, бинарный поиск*** (и не нужны никакие деревья)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бинарное дерево поиска, например, желательно - сбалансированное (например, красно-черное). Тогда вставка будет выполняться за O(log N), так что в общем случае весь масив данных соберется за O(N log N).

Вопрос в том - нужна ли отсортированность в любой момент времени, или только по окончании получения всех данных? Если по окончании - то не мучьтесь, собирайте в массив (`vector` C++) и сортируйте по окончании работы.

Если нужна отсортированность в любой момент времени - то то же красно-черное дерево (в случае C++ - берем готовый `set`).

**Update** с учетом уточненного задания - быстрого поиска по ключу.

В этом случае имеет смысл подумать о хешировании - отсортированность для быстрого поиска не является обязательной.

Язык у вас не указан, но в C++ ваша задача быстрого поиска значения по ключу укладывается в `map` и `unordered_map`.

Comment: 1. Бинарные деревья исследовал, но увы, не подходят по ряду причин. Если вдаваться подробности, то вот цель: ["Быстрый поиск по ключу среди пары ключ-значение"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/982826/246927). Нужен именно отсортированный массив в любой момент времени. Не по окончанию получения всех данных, а именно пересортировка после получения каждого элемента. По этому массиву в любой момент времени может производиться бинарный поиск.
2. Время вставки совершенно непринципиально. Зато крайне критично время бинатного поиска по этому массиву, фактически время выборки данных.

Comment: Наиболее подходящий мне вариант бинарных деревьев это двоичная куча. Но по прикидкам массив должен рабоать быстрее - вот его и реализовал. Теперь ищу эффективный механизм пересортировки, если есть оптимизированный под мой случай алгоритм.

Comment: См. дополненный ответ...

Comment: Язык указывал вскользь - это чистая сишка. На ней написана вся программа. Увы, плюсы не подойдут, но ничего незаменимого в них нет ) А можно чуть подробнее про хеширование? Не понимаю идеи, как именно можно его использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас нет никакой дополнительной информации о приходящих элементах, то здесь нужна обыкновенная вставка каждого очередного приходящего элемента с бинарным поиском места для вставки - вот и все.

Если вы знаете что-то еще про приходящие элементы, то ситуация может быть иной. Например, если вы знаете, что приходящие элементы будут поступать возрастающими группами, то начиная с определенной средней длины такой группы бинарный поиск лучше заменить на линейный с запоминанием последней найденной позиции.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Очень полезная информация. Про вставку после бинарного поиска уже чуть раньше подсказали, но про следующий финт - свежая идея! Ещё раз благодарю!